# laravel - alternative to using enum since renaming columns is not supported

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

The [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) says

> Note: Renaming columns in a table with a enum column is not currently
>   supported.

What would be a best practice alternative to using an ENUM. For example, I have a `users` table with a `type` ENUM column. I might need to modify the table in the future, and being unable to because of the existence of an ENUM column is too restrictive.

Answer (score 3):

What i usually do is: Make a `types` table.

```
-----------------------
| id | type           |
-----------------------
| 1  | admin          |
-----------------------
| 2  | moderator      |
-----------------------
```

In your `users` table make a field `type_id`. And create your relation in laravel:

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Type');
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$users = Users::where('type', '=', 1)->get();
```

Or:

```
$users = User::with(['type' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 'admin');
}])->get();
```

And you can also inverse the relationship so you can query by `type` and load all the `users` like:

```
$all = Type::with('users')->where('type', '=', 'admin')->get();
```